# How to efficiently download large files (> 1GB) using box api v2

Tags: c#, box-api

I want to download large files using the [box csharp sdk](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/). There is a api called Read(File). but this `api` is a blocking call and it just  expects a stream to be written to. Ideally there should have been a `api` which takes input as limit and offset to start getting the chunk from. This will be useful in handling a scenario where in while downloading large files the connection went off in the middle. or the `app` crashed for some reason. Next time when it restart it could have asked to get the content from where it left off last time. 
As of now we have to start again from beginning

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge Box does not currently support 'chunked' downloads so it's always going to be a one-shot operation. (I'd love to be wrong about that, though.) If you wish to avoid a blocking call, consider one of the [asynchronous Read methods](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/blob/master/BoxApi.V2/IFile.cs#L182-L230):

- `Read(Action<byte[]> onSuccess, Action<Error> onFailure, ...)`
- `ReadToStream(Action<stream> onSuccess, Action<Error> onFailure, ...)`